# Update Git password for Azure

Tags: git, azure

How can I change my Git password for my Azure hosted websites?

I followed the documentation [to setup Git on Azure initially](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-git/), but now I'd like to change that password and I can't find how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by going to the Dashboard of a site, and clicking 'Reset Deployment Credentials'.

Note that this changes it for all sites, not just for this site.